# What would the regex be to match a string whether it has 1 or less apostrophes at any number of different indexes or none at all?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, regex

I really don't know Regular Expression syntax that well, but I am using a simple highlighting plug-in for jQuery, and I need it to select a word whether it has 1 or less apostrophes at any number of different indexes or none at all.

For example, say I have a string: `Tods` (note that this string *could* be anything).

I need a regular expression that could still select: `Tod's`, `To'ds`, `T'ods`, or `'Tods`. (Note that I did not include an apostrophe at the last index, as this is not necessary, although, it *probably* wouldn't hurt anything).

So far I have this code in jQuery...:

```
$("input.highlightTerm").each(function () {
    $(".resultValue").highlight($(this).val());
});
```

...where `$(this).val()` is the string that will be highlighted.

It is also possible for me to do this in C#, as I populate the hidden input fields that this jQuery code picks up (`$("input.highlightTerm")`) on server-side, using C#.

Simple C# Razor Syntax:

```
for (var n = 0; n < searchTermsArray.Length; n++)
{
    <input class="highlightTerm" type="hidden" value="@searchTermsArray[n]" />
}
```

What is the regular expression syntax I need to get this done?

**More Examples of What Should and Shouldn't Match:**

T'o'd's [Should Match]

Tod's [Should Match]

'Tods' [Should Match]

'Tods OR Tods' [Really doesn't matter, because of how the plug-in works, but I *guess* Should Match, is preferred]

Tod''s [Shouldn't Match]

''Tods [Shouldn't Match]

--Pretty much I only want matches if there is 1 or less apostrophes among any number of different indexes within the string.

Comment: Should it match a single apostrophe that is all by itself?

Comment: @talemyn No, it should not.

Comment: I would think it would be simpler to strip apostrophes from the input text before performing the match against the terms to match against. Because writing a regular expression that allows for inserted apostrophes at any point in a given word requires inserting something like `[']?` between every character in the word to be used as the pattern.

Comment: @EtanReisner Of course, if that were acceptable in my situation, that would make more sense. The problem is: The server-side code I have used, already strips out apostrophes and leaves me with `Farmers` instead of `Farmer's`. The page matches and is found okay, after a LOT of SQL functions in the queries. In short I can't really tamper with the string until after or just before the the string is put into the hidden input field for the highlight plug-in to detect.

Comment: How about `To'd's`?  Should that match?  How about `'Tods'`?

Comment: @IanMcLaird I see, that I should have been more specific. I do apologize for that, usually, I have better attention to detail than that. I will update my post to show more specific examples.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. The highlight code on the page should simply strip apostrophes from the text it is going to match against before it does its work. I assumed the highlight function was doing some amount of string matching (presumably with a regex internally or some-such thing).

Comment: @EtanReisner The highlight plug-in detects the text that is actually in the selected element. Here, the words (like Farmer's) do (and should) show the apostrophe. However, the page is already set up to (and should) find matches on `Farmer's` when the user only typed `Farmers` into the search bar.  The terms match, in part, because I strip out the apostrophes from there search words, and use a SQL `replace()` function to ensure that apostrophes are stripped out of the database values (where the website pages actually get there content). Is that any clearer, or did I just confuse you more?

Comment: Right. I'm not suggesting that you change any actual text anywhere just what the highlight function matches against. So use a regex or whatever to remove any single apostrophes from the selected element content *before* you perform the search against the value you got from your database. Leave the db alone. Leave the displayed text alone. Just change, in a local variable, the search text before you search against it.

Comment: @EtanReisner Looking closer, I don't think the plug-in has the option of replacing text before you choose to highlight whatever string you pass to it.

Comment: @EtanReisner You simply pass it an element add "." and the name of the function the plug-in uses "highlight" then pass it the string that you want it to highlight all the instances of within the element's text. Like this `$("#elementID").highlight("textToHighlightEachOf")`

Comment: @EtanReisner In short, I don't get to play with the contents of the element that the plug-in matches against, because it is utilized after actually selecting an element. I suppose I *could* grab the text with `.text()` and dump the replaced text into another hidden input field, though, then test against that. I will probably try that, after lunch.

Comment: Right. I was suggesting modifying the part of the highlight function that actually performs the match.

Comment: @EtanReisner OIC what you're saying, you mean modify part of the plug-in itself? (My self-suggestion I made in my previous comment is of course not going to work. I don't know what I was thinking there).

Comment: Yes. I mean modify the highlight function so that it modifies the input it gets from the element to match your criteria and then matches against the to-highlight text.

Comment: @EtanReisner That is a very good idea. I have a few things to check into here (including this), to see what I can get working, but I just want to say, "Thank you," to everyone who has been helping me through this.

Comment: @EtanReisner Well, I suppose the syntax within the plug-in, however short it is, is still a bit beyond me. I don't understand enough of it to pinpoint when I could filter away apostrophes.

Comment: One last question.  Should the original string `Tods` (no apostrophes)  match the regex?

Comment: @IanMcLaird Just saw your comment, and Yes, it should. I will get right to trying your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure the string has length and that there are no double-apostrophes (this rules out triples and higher as well).  Then test the string for containing only word characters or apostrophes.

```
var re = /^[\w']*$/;
function checkForApostrophe(str) {
    if ( !str.length ) { return; }
    if ( str.indexOf("''") !== -1 ) { return; }
    if ( str.charAt(str.length-1) === "'" ) { return; }

    return re.test(str);
}
```

Replace '\w' in the regex with [a-zA-Z], possibly including [0-9] depending on your requirements.

The question is a little difficult to understand exactly what you want, so if this isn't quite right please comment.

Comment: I hate to ask this, because I can usually always figure it out, but how do I implement this? I tried it the way I would have expected `$(".resultValue").highlight(checkForApostrophe(highlightString));` but it didn't work.

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar with the highlight plugin you are using or what exactly your use case is.  This is a function that accepts a string and returns true if it satisfies your criteria and either false or undefined if not ( which are both falsey).  If that doesn't satisfy your needs you may need to rephrase your question, or open a new one that is more specific to how you need to invoke it.

Comment: Okay, I think I was using it wrong then. I didn't expect the true/false return.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I'm not really sure what I could do with a true/false return. If it returns true, that it does meet the criteria, then I think I'm pretty much right back where I started.

Comment: I guess I should have specified that I need the string that satisfies the criteria (instead of just the string itself, exactly) to search against with the highlight plug-in.

Comment: Well, if this function returns true, then the value you passed in satisfies the criteria.  You passed it into the function, so you should still have a reference to it.  Alternatively you could change the last line to `return re.test(str) ? str : false;` and it will simply return the string you passed in.

Comment: Right, but I don't need the string I passed in. I know what it is already. The string I passed in could be "Farmers", and I would need to highlight "Farmer's" (or variants) in the element I am searching against. I think I have confused the issue, confusing you guys (and myself) in the process. Again, I apologize, I think I'm thinking about it so much, I lost sight of what I really needed here. I'm not sure there *is* a way to do what I want here, based on this plug-in at hand. I would need to pass the `.highlight` function every possible combination of what regex *could* find on the string.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it satisfies the criteria of my OP. That having been said, I think it is time for a new question where I don't ask questions that are unsuitable for the goal at hand. Thanks for your time and patience.

Answer (score 2):

I think after reading the comments on the other answers, I've figured out what it is you're going for.  You don't need a single regex that can do this for any possible input, you already *have* input, and you need to build a regex that matches it and its variations.  What you need to do is this.

```
var re = new RegExp("'?" + "tods".split("").join("'?") + "'?")
```

This will create a regex that matches in the way you're describing, provided it's OK that it *also* matches the original string.

In this case, the above line builds this regex:

```
/'?t'?o'?d'?s'?/
```

This may still not be 100% right.  You know, since I don't have that highlight function around myself to play with, but I think it should get you on the right track.

Comment: +1 - Thank you for your help Ian, I misrepresented this question. I'm sry about that, but I have just posted a new question worded better and less confusing (I hope). This post also includes the highlight function itself and may clarify things a bit. I have accepted Mike Edward's answer on this post, as he did his job in satisfying the question in the OP, but if you could just copy your answer to the new question (found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734758/how-can-i-match-and-return-multiple-instances-of-a-string-where-single-apostrop), then you could...

Comment: ...get yourself an easy accept and another upvote. (I have done this so as to not confuse future viewers of this question).

Comment: How could I use this regular expression to populate, say, a C# list or array?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to do something like this !

```
 function checkForApostrophe(str) {
        var length = str.length;
        if (length != 0)
        {
            // Makes sure string contains only Alphabets, numbers and apostrophe : Nothing else
            if (str.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9']*")) {
                // makes sure there is only one or zero apostrophe
                if ((str.indexOf("'") != -1) && (str.indexOf("'") == str.lastIndexOf("'"))) {
                    // Makes sure there is no apostrophe stranded at the end 
                    if (str.lastIndexOf("'") == length - 1)
                        return false
                    else
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please check the update in my post. You may have (through no fault of your own) misunderstood my requirements. I say this based off of the comments in your code.

Comment: I think my code takes care of everything... ! 
Please follow my code along with comments ... It will help you...

Comment: Now that I think about it, I'm not really sure what I could do with a true/false return. If it returns true, that it does satisfy the criteria, then I think I'm pretty much right back where I started.