# How can I match and return multiple instances of a string, where single apostrophes could be contained at any index?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, regex

*Please note, the 'C#' tag was included intentionally, because I could accept C# syntax for my answer here, as I have the option of doing this both client-side and server-side. Read the **'Things You May Want To Know'** section below. Also, the 'regex' tag was included because there is a strong possibility that the use of regular expressions is the best approach to this problem.*

I have the following highlight Plug-In found here:

http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html

**And here is the code in that plug-in:**

```
/*

highlight v4

Highlights arbitrary terms.

<http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html>

MIT license.

Johann Burkard
<http://johannburkard.de>
<mailto:jb@eaio.com>

*/

jQuery.fn.highlight = function(pat) {
 function innerHighlight(node, pat) {
  var skip = 0;
  if (node.nodeType == 3) {
   var pos = node.data.toUpperCase().indexOf(pat);
   if (pos >= 0) {
    var spannode = document.createElement('span');
    spannode.className = 'highlight';
    var middlebit = node.splitText(pos);
    var endbit = middlebit.splitText(pat.length);
    var middleclone = middlebit.cloneNode(true);
    spannode.appendChild(middleclone);
    middlebit.parentNode.replaceChild(spannode, middlebit);
    skip = 1;
   }
  }
  else if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.childNodes && !/(script|style)/i.test(node.tagName)) {
   for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; ++i) {
    i += innerHighlight(node.childNodes[i], pat);
   }
  }
  return skip;
 }
 return this.length && pat && pat.length ? this.each(function() {
  innerHighlight(this, pat.toUpperCase());
 }) : this;
};

jQuery.fn.removeHighlight = function() {
 return this.find("span.highlight").each(function() {
  this.parentNode.firstChild.nodeName;
  with (this.parentNode) {
   replaceChild(this.firstChild, this);
   normalize();
  }
 }).end();
};
```

This plug-in works pretty easily.

If I wanted to highlight all instances of the word "Farm" within the following element...(cont.)

```
<div id="#myDiv">Farmers farm at Farmer's Market</div>
```

...(cont.) all I would need to do is use:

```
$("#myDiv").highlight("farm");
```

And then it would highlight the first four characters in "Farmers" and "Farmer's", as well as the entire word "farm" within the `div#myDiv`

No problem there, but I would like it to use this:

```
$("#myDiv").highlight("Farmers");
```

And have it highlight both "Farmers" AND "Farmer's". The problem is, of course, that I don't know the value of the search term (The term "Farmers" in this example) at runtime. So I would need to detect all possibilities of no more than one apostrophe at each index of the string. For instance, if I called `$("#myDiv").highlight("Farmers");` like in my code example above, I would also need to highlight each instance of the original string, plus:

- 'Farmers
- F'armers
- Fa'rmers
- Far'mers
- Farm'ers
- Farme'rs
- Farmer's
- Farmers'

Instances where two or more apostrophes are found sid-by-side, like "Fa''rmers" should, of course, not be highlighted.

I suppose it would be nice if I could include (to be highlighted) words like "Fa'rmer's", but I won't push my luck, and I would be doing well just to get matches like those found in my bulleted list above, where only one apostrophe appears in the string, at all.

I thought about regex, but I don't know the syntax that well, not to mention that I don't think I could do anything with a true/false return value.

Is there anyway to accomplish what I need here?

**Things You May Want To Know:**

1. The highlight plug-in takes care of all the case insensitive requirements I need, so no need to worry about that, at all.
2. Syntax provided in JavaScript, jQuery, or even C# is acceptable, considering the hidden input fields I use the values from, client-side, are populated, server-side, with my C# code.
3. The C# code that populates the hidden input fields uses Razor (i.e., I am in a C#.Net Web-Pages w/ WebMatrix environment. This code is very simple, however, and looks like this:

   `for (var n = 0; n < searchTermsArray.Length; n++)`

   `{`

   ```
   <input class="highlightTerm" type="hidden" value="@searchTermsArray[n]" />
   ```

   `}`

Comment: Or you would need a dictionary that's capable of indicating that a possible permutation of `Farmers` is `Farmer's`.

Comment: @neoistheone If I understand you correctly, I think a Dictionary list, so long as it contained the correct values, should work just fine.

Comment: Yeah, so in C# it might be `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` maybe.

Comment: @neoistheone Sounds great, only, since "Farmers" could be *any* string, I am not sure of the RegEx or method I would need to get this dictionary list populated.

Comment: @neoistheone Admittedly, I am not good with regex at this point in my ever-ongoing education in programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm copying this answer from your earlier question.

I think after reading the comments on the other answers, I've figured out what it is you're going for.  You don't need a single regex that can do this for any possible input, you already *have* input, and you need to build a regex that matches it and its variations.  What you need to do is this.  To be clear, since you misinterpreted in your question, the following syntax is actually in JavaScript.

```
var re = new RegExp("'?" + "farmers".split("").join("'?") + "'?", "i")
```

What this does is take your input string, `"farmers"` and split it into a list of the individual characters.

```
"farmers".split("") == [ 'f', 'a', 'r', 'm', 'e', 'r', 's' ]
```

It then stitches the characters back together again with `"'?"` between them.  In a regular expression, this means that the `'` character will be optional.  I add the same particle to the beginning and end of the expression to match at the beginning and end of the string as well.

This will create a regex that matches in the way you're describing, provided it's OK that it *also* matches the original string.

In this case, the above line builds this regex:

```
/'?f'?a'?r'?m'?e'?r'?s'?/
```

**EDIT**

After looking at this a bit, and the function you're using, I think your best bet will be to modify the highlight function to use a regex instead of a straight string replacement.  I don't think it'll even be that hard to deal with.  Here's a completely untested stab at it.

```
function innerHighlight(node, pat) {
    var skip = 0;
    if (node.nodeType == 3) {
        var matchResult = pat.exec(node.data);  // exec the regex instead of toUpperCase-ing the string
        var pos = matchResult !== null ? matchResult.index : -1;  // index is the location of where the matching text is found
        if (pos >= 0) {
            var spannode = document.createElement('span');
            spannode.className = 'highlight';
            var middlebit = node.splitText(pos);
            var endbit = middlebit.splitText(matchResult[0].length);  // matchResult[0] is the last matching characters.
            var middleclone = middlebit.cloneNode(true);
            spannode.appendChild(middleclone);
            middlebit.parentNode.replaceChild(spannode, middlebit);
            skip = 1;
        }
    }
    else if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.childNodes && !/(script|style)/i.test(node.tagName)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; ++i) {
            i += innerHighlight(node.childNodes[i], pat);
        }
    }
    return skip;
 }
```

What I'm attempting to do here is keep the existing logic, but use the Regex that I built to do the finding and splitting of the string.  Note that I'm not doing the toUpper call anymore, but that I've made the regex case insensitive instead.  As noted, I didn't test this at all, but it seems like it should be pretty close to a working solution.  Enough to get you started anyway.

**Note** that this won't get you your hidden fields.  I'm not sure what you need those for, but this will (if it's right) take care of highlighting the string.

Comment: Thanks Ian! If you could just explain a tad bit further, I will be all set to try your solution. All I need is to be able to use `re` to build an array or C# list.

Comment: @VoidKing In _RegExp_ `?` means "the last bit is optional", so here it is saying "[...] then an optional apostophe, then [...]".

Comment: @VoidKing `re` here is a _Regular Expression_ that will match the instances you asked for.

Comment: @PaulS. Thanks for that! I was trying to break it down in my head, and I kind of thought that's what it was doing, but wasn't sure. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: I'll expand the answer with a bit more info, and show how I derived this.

Comment: Okay, Ian, keep in mind though that I will end up *needing* all of the possible string values that do match this RegEx, like in an array or list, so I can iterate over them in C# to populate as many hidden input fields as I need. The original search term, plus all its variations will need to be highlighted, so I'll actually need all possible variations of the string.

Comment: Oops, didn't realize it was JavaScript :S LOL, that works, too, of course. But can I get it in something I can iterate over, or am I misunderstanding some of the power of RegEx?

Comment: Do you want the ones that *actually occur* in the searched text, or just every possible combination?

Comment: Every possible combination was what I intended, but either way is totally acceptable. If the highlight plug-in doesn't find the text, it simply won't highlight anything, so I can iterate over values that aren't actually in the text with no problem, at all.

Comment: Actually, I think it will be much easier and probably less error-prone to simply have "just every possible combination."

Comment: My hope was that the highlight function understood regex to do its search, and would automatically highlight all matching substrings in the searched text.  From the example, though, that probably won't work.

Comment: Yes, sadly, I already tried passing it just the regular expression, but it was to no avail. Does there not exist some logic that can compile an array based off of a string's regex matches?

Comment: No, because even a very simple regex like `a*` has an infinite number of potentially matching strings.  You can get all of the actual matches in a real string, but not every conceivable matching string.

Comment: Can we not go the route of getting all of the actual matches in a real string, or is it, again, time for a new question?

Comment: While, this didn't really do the trick, I believe that the approach here is right. Inside the plug-in is probably where this code needs to be, I just can't get the syntax right :S In any event, I have used something else in C#, to just add an apostrophe just before the last character of the given string, and I think this is taking care of at least 95% of my problem, so I think I can settle with that. Thanks for your help, and I am accepting this answer on the grounds that the approach is at least a starting point for anyone else who may have a similar problem.